# Howto cut use the find and replace in vs2008 to cut the spesific string's head and tail?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, replace, find

e.g.
In my legacy code, there are lots of template usages. But I refactored the code base to limit the template usage only in base classes. Then here comes the problem, Is there a fast way (using find and replace, maybe) to change:

> "`SomeTemplate<some_var>`"  into just "some_var"  ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Find and Replace, expand `Find Options` and tick `Use Regular Expressions` then replace:

```
SomeTemplate\<{:i}\>
```

with

```
\1
```

The `{}` tags the group and `:i` matches a C++ identifier.  The `\1` references the first tagged group.

EDIT:
If you also have namespaces then you'll need a more complex regular expression. If you know that you have at most one level of namespace then probably the quickest thing to do is just do a second pass to replace:

```
SomeTemplate\<{:i}\:\:{:i}\>
```

with

```
\1::\2
```

Note that because ':', '<' and '>' have a special meaning in regular expressions they have to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that indeed helped! But when some_var contains "." like "Somenamespace.some_var" the replace fails. Wondering why's that...

Comment: I did the work with \<{:i}\.\{:i}\> in C# code for one level namespace ref. and \.\. && \.\.\. and so on for multi-level ref.